# How do I prevent a page reload when submitting a form in Rails using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to use ajax to submit a form in Rails. The form_for tag looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @applicant, remote: true, html: {class: "form", id: "regform"} do |f| %>
```

I added some js validations to the form, so I trigger a submit when the validations are passed:

```
$('#register-form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
  errorMessage();
} else {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#regform').trigger('submit.rails')
}
```

And I'm trying to add some callback functions:

```
$("#regform").on('ajax:success', successMessage);
```

But when the form submits it reloads the page so it never gets to the success callback. The form is saving correctly but I haven't figured out how to prevent the page reload. Any ideas?

Comment: change the submit button to normal button and on clicking it do all the validation and then submit the form.